# Assigning next pointer in a structure definition = NULL, throws error

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, linked-list, typedef

Why this error is being thrown for below code.

```
Error: error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token
  struct node_s *next=NULL;
```

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_s {
    int data;
    struct node_s *next=NULL;
} node;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `NULL` initialization of the pointer. An initialization is only allowed at the declaration.

```
typedef struct node_s {
     int data;
     struct node_s *next;
}node;
```

You can do `node a = { .next = NULL };` to initialize the pointer during the declaration.